# passing variable from bash shell to sql file to oracle table

Tags: bash, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have set variables in `my .sh` file (ex. `ENV=$1 RELEASE_ID=$2`) within `my.sh` file. I `sqlplus` into my sql file like

```
sqlplus -S $username/password@destination @/path/copysetup/insert.sql
```

I want to pass variables `ENV=$1` `RELEASE_ID=$2` calling from a unix prompt into my sql file as

```
copysetup.sh env01 release 1.0
```

from my sql file I want to pass the same variable into an oracle table

```
insert into table...
```

Can someone assist on how to pass variable from bash shell script to sql file and ultimately insert the into my oracle table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the parameters on the command line:

```
sqlplus -S $username/password@destination @/path/copysetup/insert.sql $ENV $RELEASE_ID
```

then in the SQL script they become &1 and &2 (ensure you have `set scan on` at the top of the SQL script)

eg

```
set scan on
insert into foo (env, release) values ('&1', '&2');
commit;
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and &1 and &2 are inserted into my oracle table vice ENVXX release 1.XX. It doesn't seem to be picking up the variables from my .sh file. I am defining the variable though my unix prompt. So I call to my .sh file like such (ex. copysetup.sh ENV01 release 1.00). My hopes is that when I specifiy what I want passed in unix it will pass those variables from my .sh file to the sql file and ultimately insert them into my oracle table. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @user1813261 if you start sql plus manually and execute your sql file as `@/path/copysetup/insert.sql test test` does test and test get inserted or &1 &2 still? if &1 still whats the output of `show define` and `show scan` when run in sqlplus?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your insert.sql file is the one which you'd like to insert an environment variable (or any bash variable), you can use [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) to find/replace a some placeholder text with your desired value. For instance, if your insert.sql file looked something like

```
INSERT INTO @mytable VALUES (1,'sometext');
```

You could use sed to find/replace the `@mytable` string with the data stored in `$MYVAR` using the following syntax in a bash script

```
sed "s/@mytable/$MYVAR" insert.sql > modifiedinsert.sql
```

Now this would generate a new file, modifiedinsert.sql which you'd then pass into sqlplus.